# How mention on discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

please help, how to mention the user in the message? I can't find the answer on the internet. my code:

```js
  const exampleeEmbedd = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#53db56')
  .setTitle('  [] Приветствуем нового путника!')
  .setDescription(' Приветствуем вас ' + /*MENTION*/ + '!\nДобро пожаловать на международный сервер режима Geopolitics. \nЗдесь вы можете присоеденится к существующему городу/государству, либо зарегистрировать свой город/государство.')
  .setURL('')
  .setAuthor('Имперский Бот', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/nWASMV-67mx7guRheeUpvyD_cb6X2NkxUMH4PtbweyA/%3Fsize%3D512/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/916617120064884796/5028d4861b407575072686657b3c2e9a.png' )
  .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL())
  .addFields(
  )
  .setImage('')
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter('asdas', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/nWASMV-67mx7guRheeUpvyD_cb6X2NkxUMH4PtbweyA/%3Fsize%3D512/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/916617120064884796/5028d4861b407575072686657b3c2e9a.png');
  mess.channel.send( { embeds: [exampleeEmbedd] } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Discord.js converts mentions for you automatically when interpreted as a string.

`"Foo" + user + "Bar"` converts to `Foo<@!1234567890>Bar`.

Using template strings:

```
`Foo${user}Bar`
```

In cases where you only have the user ID, you can do this manually:

```
"Foo<@!" + userId + ">Bar"
// or
`Foo<@!${userId}>Bar`
```

Ensure that `userId` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `${user}` string or `${user.tag}`, so your bot will mention a user.

Make sure you placed `let user = message.mentions.members.first()` above the embed

The example:

```
   const exampleeEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('an embed')
  .setDescription(`Hello ${user}!`)
  mess.channel.send({ embeds: exampleeEmbed });
```

Also make sure you enclose your message as  ``` `` ```

Comment: I believe in v13 you'll have to add `.toString()` even though it's being stringified